# Can't find ListBoxItem control in PivotItem if not visited

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a Pivot control with 3 PivotItems and I have to access the controls which are in those containers. Here is the code example:

```
<Pivot x:Name="rootPivot">
    <PivotItem Header="1">
        <TimePicker x:Name="VisualInspectionOfRunningLightsHour"  Header="Visual inspection" Width="400"></TimePicker>
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="2">
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="600" Margin="24,24,24,24">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="600">
                <TextBlock Text="Look-out set and taken in at" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="3" >
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid Name="TestGrid">
                    <TimePicker x:Name="FireInspectionCarriedOutAt" Header="Fire inspection carried out at" Width="400"></TimePicker>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel>
                <ListView Name="listViewTest">
                    <ListViewItem>
                        <TextBox Text="123"></TextBox>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>
                        <TextBox Text="234"></TextBox>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>
                        <TextBox Text="456"></TextBox>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>
                        <TextBox Text="789"></TextBox>
                    </ListViewItem>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

I can access the regular controls using this.FindName() or using VisualTreeHelper class. But the problem is I am not able to get controls which are in ListView/GridView until I visit the PivotItem at least once which contains that ListView/GridView. In my scenario, I need to access the TextBox controls which are in **PivotItem 3** as ListViewItem without visiting that tab. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: how you want to access textbox controls or what you want to do ? can you show some c#

Comment: Pivot uses virtualization, so relying on accessing from code behind isn't the best way. If you still needs it, then do it in loaded event of the pivotItem, so that it's guaranteed to be loaded.

You can also try to use binding and viewmodel to handle your data, in this case you don't need to worry whether the controls is loaded or not.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The problem is here are can't use binding since we are loading the UI template at runtime which could be changed at any time. Our PivotItem might contains Telerik's Rad Grid and we used the grid loaded event to access the items. But the problem is items are not generated immediately even after the loaded event fired. We still had to use delay for 500/1000ms to access those items after the loaded event. This is just a workaround and we are searching for a better solution since using delay is a good way to solve this kind of problems.